# Bootstrap Table: server side pagination parameters don't reach server

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I've setup a Boostrap table like this:

```
$('#usertable').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'User ID'
    }, {
        field: 'username',
        title: 'Username'
    }, {
        field: 'email',
        title: 'Email'
    }],
    sidePagination: 'server',
    url: 'http://devapi.vreserver.com/api/users/',
    pagination: true
});
```

The test api server works fine (as I can see by a curl request). Adding the additional GET parameters in the URL (?order=desc&offset=0&limit=10) the api returns just 10 rows (starting from the latest id):
[image: cURL test]

But the result bootstrap table has always all user rows - and also changing page doesn't affect the result.

Having control on the server I saw that the GET parameters passed by requests, that are triggered by bootstrap table - simply doesn't exist on server side. But any other request (like from other js scripts on the same app), with the same url request (?order=desc&offset=0&limit=10) acts well.

Any clue where should I look for a fix to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem still here, but found a workaround...

Added on server side a route to accept also POST to retrieve users data, then added:

```
method: 'post',
url: 'new-url-for-post'
```

in table options.

Now it works, but I still cannot understand why GET is not working. :)